# Calendar cannot initialize null pointer exception on 5.1 API level

Tags: java, android

This time reminder class, time reminder is crashing on click and erroe goes on "custom.showDialogue" and the error is the following:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.appmetrik.notestakingapp, PID: 18607
                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.app.notes.CustomDateTimePicker.showDialog()' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at com.app.notes.AddReminder.onClick(AddReminder.java:261)

```
public class AddReminder extends AppCompatActivity implements    
android.view.View.OnClickListener`{

    CustomDateTimePicker custom = null;

    TextView txt_Time;
    TextView txt_Date;
    TextView txt_Day;
    EditText et_Reminder_Title;
    EditText et_Reminder_Description;
    ImageButton btn_Submit_Reminder;
    public static String var_Reminder_Title;
    public String var_Reminder_Description;
    public String var_Reminder_Time;
    public String var_Reminder_Date;
    public String var_Reminder_Day;
    public int var_Not_Day;
    public int var_Not_Month;
    public int var_Not_Year;
    public int var_Not_Hour;
    public int var_Not_Min;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_reminder);

        txt_Time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEditTime);
        txt_Time.setOnClickListener(this);

        txt_Date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEditDate);
        txt_Date.setOnClickListener(this);

        txt_Day = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEditDay);
        txt_Day.setOnClickListener(this);

        et_Reminder_Title= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEditReminderTitle);
        et_Reminder_Description = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etReminderDescription);

        btn_Submit_Reminder = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnSubmitReminder);
        btn_Submit_Reminder.setOnClickListener(this);

        try {
            custom = new CustomDateTimePicker(AddReminder.this,
                    new CustomDateTimePicker.ICustomDateTimeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onSet(Dialog dialog, Calendar calendarSelected,
                                          Date dateSelected, int year, String monthFullName,
                                          String monthShortName, int monthNumber, int date,
                                          String weekDayFullName, String weekDayShortName,
                                          int hour24, int hour12, int min, int sec,
                                          String AM_PM) {

                            txt_Time.setText(hour12 + ":" + min + " " + AM_PM);
                            txt_Date.setText(calendarSelected
                                    .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                                    + "/" + (monthNumber + 1) + "/" + year);
                            txt_Day.setText(weekDayFullName);

                            var_Not_Hour = hour24;
                            var_Not_Min = min;
                            var_Not_Month = monthNumber;
                            var_Not_Day = calendarSelected
                                    .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                            var_Not_Year = year;
                        }


                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {

                        }
                    });
            /**
             * Pass Directly current time format it will return AM and PM if you set
             * false
             */
            custom.set24HourFormat(false);
            /**
             * Pass Directly current data and time to show when ita pop up
             */
            custom.setDate(Calendar.getInstance());
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(AddReminder.this, "Sorry! Calendar Initialization Failed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

       findViewById(R.id.button_date).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        custom.showDialog();
                    }
                });
    }
      public void getValues(){
        var_Reminder_Title = et_Reminder_Title.getText().toString();
        var_Reminder_Time = txt_Time.getText().toString();
        var_Reminder_Date = txt_Date.getText().toString();
        var_Reminder_Day = txt_Day.getText().toString();
        var_Reminder_Description = et_Reminder_Description.getText().toString();

    }

    public boolean validate()
    {

        boolean allValid = true;


        if(et_Reminder_Title.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0)
    {
        allValid = false;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                et_Reminder_Title.setError("Please Enter a Reminder Title here");
            }
        });

    }
        if(txt_Time.getText() == "Time")
        {
            allValid = false;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    et_Reminder_Title.setError("Tap Here to Select a Due Date and Time");
                }
            });

        }
        return allValid;
    }
    public void addReminder(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("NTA_DB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        try {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reminders(ReminderId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ReminderTitle Text,ReminderTime Text,ReminderDate Text,ReminderDay Text, ReminderDescription Text);");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO reminders(ReminderTitle,ReminderTime,ReminderDate,ReminderDay,ReminderDescription) VALUES('"+var_Reminder_Title+"','"+var_Reminder_Time+"','"+var_Reminder_Date+"','"+var_Reminder_Day+"','"+var_Reminder_Description+"');");
            db.close();

            Toast.makeText(AddReminder.this, "" +
                    "Reminder Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(AddReminder.this, "Sorry! Reminder Cannot be Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            db.close();
        }

    }

    public void addNotification(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("NTA_DB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        try {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS notifications(NotificationId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NotificationTitle Text);");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO notifications(NotificationTitle) VALUES('"+var_Reminder_Title+"');");
            db.close();

            Toast.makeText(AddReminder.this, "" +
                    "Notification Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(AddReminder.this, "Sorry! Notification Cannot be Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            db.close();
        }

    }

    public void remind(){
        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
        // set for 30 seconds later
        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + 30000, alarmIntent);
        Toast.makeText(AddReminder.this, "Set Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    public void al(){

        // for Alarm 25/12/2012 at 12.00
        Calendar myAlarmDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        myAlarmDate.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        myAlarmDate.set(var_Not_Year, var_Not_Month, var_Not_Day, var_Not_Hour, var_Not_Min, 0);

        //Toast.makeText(AddReminder.this, ""+var_Not_Year+" "+ var_Not_Month+" "+ var_Not_Day+" "+var_Not_Hour+" "+var_Not_Min+" "+ 0, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       //Create alarm manager
        AlarmManager alarmMgr0 = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

//Create pending intent & register it to your alarm notifier class
        Intent intent0 = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
       //intent0.putExtra("Ringtone",getResources().getResourceName(R.raw.bbm_tone));
        intent0.putExtra("Heading",var_Reminder_Title);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent0 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent0, 0);

//set timer you want alarm to work (here I have set it to 7.20pm)
        //Intent intent0 = new Intent(this, OldEntryRemover.class);
       /* Calendar timeOff9 = Calendar.getInstance();
        timeOff9.set(Calendar.MONTH,12);
        timeOff9.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
        timeOff9.set(Calendar.YEAR,2015);
        timeOff9.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
        timeOff9.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
        timeOff9.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
*/
//set that timer as a RTC Wakeup to alarm manager object
        alarmMgr0.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, myAlarmDate.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent0);
       // Toast.makeText(AddReminder.this, "Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed ()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(AddReminder.this, FrontScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.txtEditTime || v.getId() == R.id.txtEditDate || v.getId() == R.id.txtEditDay){
//            custom.showDialog();
        }
        else if(v.getId() == R.id.imgBtnSubmitReminder) {
            if (validate() == true) {
                getValues();
                addReminder();
                // addNotification();
                al();
                Intent intent = new Intent(AddReminder.this, FrontScreen.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is custom date time picker class which is having the method showDialogue and it is using in the previous class. It is working perfectly on the version is less than 5.0 API but it is crashing on the version of 5.1 error is datetimepicker cannot be initialized.

```
public class CustomDateTimePicker implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {
        private DatePicker datePicker;
        private TimePicker timePicker;
        private ViewSwitcher viewSwitcher;

        private final int SET_DATE = 100, SET_TIME = 101, SET = 102, CANCEL = 103;

        private Button btn_setDate, btn_setTime, btn_set, btn_cancel;

        private Calendar calendar_date = null;

        private Activity activity;

        private ICustomDateTimeListener iCustomDateTimeListener = null;

        private Dialog dialog;

        private boolean is24HourView = true, isAutoDismiss = true;

        private int selectedHour, selectedMinute;

        public CustomDateTimePicker(Activity a,
                                    ICustomDateTimeListener customDateTimeListener) {
            activity = a;
            iCustomDateTimeListener = customDateTimeListener;

            dialog = new Dialog(activity);

           // Context context = new ContextThemeWrapper(new MyContextWrapper, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog);


            dialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    resetData();
                }
            });
/*
            dialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    resetData();
                }
            });*/

            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            View dialogView = getDateTimePickerLayout();
            dialog.setContentView(dialogView);
        }






    public View getDateTimePickerLayout() {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams linear_match_wrap = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams linear_wrap_wrap = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams frame_match_wrap = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams button_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);

            LinearLayout linear_main = new LinearLayout(activity);
            linear_main.setLayoutParams(linear_match_wrap);
            linear_main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            linear_main.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

            LinearLayout linear_child = new LinearLayout(activity);
            linear_child.setLayoutParams(linear_wrap_wrap);
            linear_child.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            LinearLayout linear_top = new LinearLayout(activity);
            linear_top.setLayoutParams(linear_match_wrap);

            btn_setDate = new Button(activity);
            btn_setDate.setLayoutParams(button_params);
            btn_setDate.setText("Set Date");
            btn_setDate.setId(SET_DATE);
            btn_setDate.setOnClickListener(this);

            btn_setTime = new Button(activity);
            btn_setTime.setLayoutParams(button_params);
            btn_setTime.setText("Set Time");
            btn_setTime.setId(SET_TIME);
            btn_setTime.setOnClickListener(this);

            linear_top.addView(btn_setDate);
            linear_top.addView(btn_setTime);

            viewSwitcher = new ViewSwitcher(activity);
            viewSwitcher.setLayoutParams(frame_match_wrap);

            datePicker = new DatePicker(activity);
            timePicker = new TimePicker(activity);
            timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    selectedHour = hourOfDay;
                    selectedMinute = minute;
                }
            });

            viewSwitcher.addView(timePicker);
            viewSwitcher.addView(datePicker);

            LinearLayout linear_bottom = new LinearLayout(activity);
            linear_match_wrap.topMargin = 8;
            linear_bottom.setLayoutParams(linear_match_wrap);

            btn_set = new Button(activity);
            btn_set.setLayoutParams(button_params);
            btn_set.setText("Set");
            btn_set.setId(SET);
            btn_set.setOnClickListener(this);

            btn_cancel = new Button(activity);
            btn_cancel.setLayoutParams(button_params);
            btn_cancel.setText("Cancel");
            btn_cancel.setId(CANCEL);
            btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(this);

            linear_bottom.addView(btn_set);
            linear_bottom.addView(btn_cancel);

            linear_child.addView(linear_top);
            linear_child.addView(viewSwitcher);
            linear_child.addView(linear_bottom);

            linear_main.addView(linear_child);

            //Invisible Calender View
            datePicker.getCalendarView().setVisibility(View.GONE);

            return linear_main;
        }
        public void showDialog() {
            if (!dialog.isShowing()) {
                if (calendar_date == null)
                    calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();

                selectedHour = calendar_date.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                selectedMinute = calendar_date.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                timePicker.setIs24HourView(is24HourView);
                timePicker.setCurrentHour(selectedHour);
                timePicker.setCurrentMinute(selectedMinute);

                datePicker.updateDate(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                        calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        calendar_date.get(Calendar.DATE));

                dialog.show();

                btn_setDate.performClick();
                btn_setTime.performClick();

            }
        }

        public void setAutoDismiss(boolean isAutoDismiss) {
            this.isAutoDismiss = isAutoDismiss;
        }

        public void dismissDialog() {
            if (!dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();
        }

        public void setDate(Calendar calendar) {
            if (calendar != null)
                calendar_date = calendar;
        }

        public void setDate(Date date) {
            if (date != null) {
                calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar_date.setTime(date);
            }
        }

        public void setDate(int year, int month, int day) {
            if (month < 12 && month >= 0 && day < 32 && day >= 0 && year > 100
                    && year < 3000) {
                calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar_date.set(year, month, day);
            }

        }

        public void setTimeIn24HourFormat(int hourIn24Format, int minute) {
            if (hourIn24Format < 24 && hourIn24Format >= 0 && minute >= 0
                    && minute < 60) {
                if (calendar_date == null)
                    calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();

                calendar_date.set(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                        calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        calendar_date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), hourIn24Format,
                        minute);

                is24HourView = true;
            }
        }

        public void setTimeIn12HourFormat(int hourIn12Format, int minute,
                                          boolean isAM) {
            if (hourIn12Format < 13 && hourIn12Format > 0 && minute >= 0
                    && minute < 60) {
                if (hourIn12Format == 12)
                    hourIn12Format = 0;

                int hourIn24Format = hourIn12Format;

                if (!isAM)
                    hourIn24Format += 12;

                if (calendar_date == null)
                    calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();

                calendar_date.set(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                        calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        calendar_date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), hourIn24Format,
                        minute);

                is24HourView = false;
            }
        }

        public void set24HourFormat(boolean is24HourFormat) {
            is24HourView = is24HourFormat;
        }

    public interface ICustomDateTimeListener {
            public void onSet(Dialog dialog, Calendar calendarSelected,
                              Date dateSelected, int year, String monthFullName,
                              String monthShortName, int monthNumber, int date,
                              String weekDayFullName, String weekDayShortName, int hour24,
                              int hour12, int min, int sec, String AM_PM);

            public void onCancel();
        }



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case SET_DATE:
                    btn_setTime.setEnabled(true);
                    btn_setDate.setEnabled(false);
                    viewSwitcher.showNext();
                    break;

                case SET_TIME:
                    btn_setTime.setEnabled(false);
                    btn_setDate.setEnabled(true);
                    viewSwitcher.showPrevious();
                    break;

                case SET:
                    if (iCustomDateTimeListener != null) {
                        int month = datePicker.getMonth();
                        int year = datePicker.getYear();
                        int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();


                        calendar_date.set(year, month, day, selectedHour,
                                selectedMinute);

                        iCustomDateTimeListener.onSet(dialog, calendar_date,
                                calendar_date.getTime(), calendar_date
                                        .get(Calendar.YEAR),
                                getMonthFullName(calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH)),
                                getMonthShortName(calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH)),
                                calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar_date
                                        .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                                getWeekDayFullName(calendar_date
                                        .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)),
                                getWeekDayShortName(calendar_date
                                        .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)), calendar_date
                                        .get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                                getHourIn12Format(calendar_date
                                        .get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)), calendar_date
                                        .get(Calendar.MINUTE), calendar_date
                                        .get(Calendar.SECOND), getAMPM(calendar_date));
                    }
                    if (dialog.isShowing() && isAutoDismiss)
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    break;

                case CANCEL:
                    if (iCustomDateTimeListener != null)
                        iCustomDateTimeListener.onCancel();
                    if (dialog.isShowing())
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    break;
            }
        }

        /**
         * @param date
         *            date in String
         * @param fromFormat
         *            format of your <b>date</b> eg: if your date is 2011-07-07
         *            09:09:09 then your format will be <b>yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss</b>
         * @param toFormat
         *            format to which you want to convert your <b>date</b> eg: if
         *            required format is 31 July 2011 then the toFormat should be
         *            <b>d MMMM yyyy</b>
         * @return formatted date
         */
        public static String convertDate(String date, String fromFormat,
                                         String toFormat) {
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(fromFormat);
                Date d = simpleDateFormat.parse(date);
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTime(d);

                simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(toFormat);
                simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
                date = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return date;
        }

        private String getMonthFullName(int monthNumber) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthNumber);

            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
            simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
            String monthName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

            return monthName;
        }

        private String getMonthShortName(int monthNumber) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthNumber);

            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
            simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
            String monthName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

            return monthName;
        }

        private String getWeekDayFullName(int weekDayNumber) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, weekDayNumber);

            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
            simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
            String weekName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

            return weekName;
        }

        private String getWeekDayShortName(int weekDayNumber) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, weekDayNumber);

            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EE");
            simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
            String weekName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

            return weekName;
        }

        private int getHourIn12Format(int hour24) {
            int hourIn12Format = 0;

            if (hour24 == 0)
                hourIn12Format = 12;
            else if (hour24 <= 12)
                hourIn12Format = hour24;
            else
                hourIn12Format = hour24 - 12;

            return hourIn12Format;
        }

        private String getAMPM(Calendar calendar) {
            String ampm = (calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == (Calendar.AM)) ? "AM"
                    : "PM";
            return ampm;
        }
enter image description here
        private void resetData() {
            calendar_date = null;
            is24HourView = true;
        }

        public static String pad(int integerToPad) {
            if (integerToPad >= 10 || integerToPad < 0)
                return String.valueOf(integerToPad);
            else
                return "0" + String.valueOf(integerToPad);
        }
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing separate onClick for button_date, when you have implemented onClick for whole activity?

Comment: Actually this code is done by previous developer and it has only one problem when the activity starts toast message shows that calendar cannot initialize. After that when I click on date picker it crashed. I do not understand this. but it is working fine with version 4